# Resizing a src iframe when its document has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

We're embedding phpBB inside our website and for the embedding to work nicely we adjust the height of the iFrame where phpBB is loaded. The code below works well but not perfectly. When the content of the frame is re-loaded (by a click in it), it awaits the .load() rather than .ready() to launch the resizing event which shows a short delay. You will notice it when you scroll down the page in the example and click to move to another page (say, select another forum).

We've tried using $('frame').ready() but it doesn't work at all.

Any good ideas to remedy this?
Please don't suggest us to copy the content of the iFrame or any such thing. Thanks.

```
function resize_iframes() {
    if ($('iframe').length < 1) return;

    // Set specific variable to represent all iframe tags.
    var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    // Resize heights.
    function iResize() {
        // Iterate through all iframes in the page.
        for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
            // Set inline style to equal the body height of the iframed content.
            iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
        }
    }

    // Check if browser is Safari or Opera.
    if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {
        // Start timer when loaded.
        $('iframe').load(function() {
            setTimeout(iResize, 0);
        });
    } else {
        // For other good browsers.
        $('iframe').load(function() {
            // Set inline style to equal the body height of the iframed content.
            try {
                this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
            } catch(err) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**  Please note it's possible to do the quicker proper resize by altering the code inside the the  itself, adding something along the lines of:

```
    window.setTimeout( function(){
        // Resize the frame we're in before it's fully loaded (images...)
        var iFrames = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        iFrames[0].style.height = iFrames[0].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
    }, 10 );
```

somewhere in the script itself. While it does solve our problem, it doesn't answer the question presented so it's left open meanwhile in case a solution is found and should be shared with the public. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `<iframe>` does not have a event similiar to the `jQuery.ready()`. So to accomplish this you have to trigger an event yourself. Include this script on all subpages:

```
var $ = window.parent.jQuery;
$(document).ready( function(){
    var iframe = window.frameElement;
    $(iframe).trigger("ready"); 
});
```

then on the page with the iframe, you can listen for ready event like this:

```
$("iframe").on("ready", function(){
    //iframe is ready
});
```